# How can I execute jQuery using Clojure and Etaoin?

Tags: jquery, selenium, clojure

I'm using Clojure + Etaoin for automated testing within Chrome. The jquery script below works in the console, but not in the REPL:

```
(js-execute d "$('#mainmenuli-report').trigger('mouseenter');")
```

Error:

```
loaders.core=> (js-execute d "$('#mainmenuli-report').trigger('mouseenter');")
Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at slingshot.support/stack-trace (support.clj:201).
throw+: {:response {:sessionId "95536bb4edb78c51dcbf593d8f8c1325", :status 17, :value {:message "javascript error: 
$ is not defined\n  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19043 x86_64)"}}, :path "session/95536bb4edb78c51dcbf593d8f8c1325/execute", :payload {:script "$('#mainmenuli-report').trigger('mouseenter');", :args []}, :method :post, :type :etaoin/http-error, :port 35178, :host "127.0.0.1", :status 200, :driver {:args ("chromedriver" "--port=35178"), :capabilities {:loggingPrefs {:browser "ALL"}, :chromeOptions {:args ("--window-size=1400,850")}}, :process #object[java.lang.ProcessImpl 0x2ef5c28d "Process[pid=20916, exitValue=\"not exited\"]"], :locator "xpath", :type :chrome, :env nil, :port 35178, :host "127.0.0.1", :url "http://127.0.0.1:35178", :session "95536bb4edb78c51dcbf593d8f8c1325"}}
```

Comment: Seems like jQuery is not available. I don't know much about Etaoin, but did you navigate to the page first so that jQuery's `$` is available?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers I believe I did but will double check, thanks